# How can you send Twilio recorded message url to third party API

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

Hi I'm trying to set up voice mail for incoming calls through Twilio Functions
and sending the call information with the recorded URL to external webhook
appreciate your suggestions on how to implement it

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    //twiml.say("Welcome We are not available at this moment. Please leave a message, and we will call you back.");
    twiml.record({ maxLength: 20,});
    twiml.hangup();

    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, except you can't do anything after `twiml.record()` but to return with `callback(null, twiml);`

So, what you could to do is:

1. Create a TwiML Bin, so you can hang up the call when the recording ends.
   Here is the code for the bin, it will just return an empty response, which in turn will hang up the call.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response />
```

When you save the bin, you can copy the URL for the bin, you'll need it in your function. The URL looks something like `https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

---

2. Change your function code to something like this (you can add more options you can find in the docs, I'll put the link at the end of this answer).

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {

    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

    // twiml.say("Welcome... Please leave a message, and we will call you back.");

    twiml.record({ 
        maxLength: 20, 
        action: 'https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        recordingStatusCallback: 'https://your_webhook_url',
        recordingStatusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
        recordingStatusCallbackEvent: 'in-progress, completed, absent'

    });

    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

If you look at the code, you can see `action` which points to the TwiML Bin you created, that is where Twilio's engine will go after the recording is done. If you omit the `action` URL, when the record is done, Twilio will come back to this function, and you'll end up in a loop (you can try it if you want).

Next, because the recording might be done, but the recording file might not be available to access, you need to use `recordingStatusCallback`, a URL on your server, a webhook, where Twilio will let you know. One of the request parameters will be `RecordingUrl`, "The URL of the recorded audio." (docs: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback-parameters)

Next, you set the method `POST` or `GET` you want Twilio to use when it hits your webhook.

Next, you tell for which events you want Twilio to hit your webhook.

---

You can read about all this in Twilio's docs here:

(https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes)

---

**Note:** If you think you can wait for some time before you use the recording URL, you can only provide the `action` with your webhook and handle the hang up on your side (respond with TwiML from your application), without the need for the TwiML bin and the `recordingStatusCallback... things`. The `RecordingUrl` is a parameter of the request to `action` too, except, like I said the file might not be available immediately.

---

How to get the "caller number":

Along with the `RecordingUrl` you get `CallSid` something like `CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` and you can use it to get (making another request from your application) information about the call including the `from` number with this code:

```js
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls('CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .fetch()
      .then(call => console.log(call.from));
```

(https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call?code-sample=code-fetch-a-call&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

Comment: Alex thank you for the detailed answer. when capturing the recording parameters I'm missing the caller number. how can I add it to the information sent to my server?